# HAProxy: configuring SSL with Let's Encrypt

Tags: ssl-certificate, haproxy, lets-encrypt

I just generate a new SSL certificate using [Let's Encrypt](https://letsencrypt.org/). Now I'm trying to configure HAProxy.

These are the folders and certificates:

```
700  archive
     |--------> 755 company.cxx
                    |------------> 644 fullchain.pem
                    |------------> 644 cert.pem
                    |------------> 644 (etc.)
```

Right now, these are the permissions of folders and **soft links** to the certificates in the `archive` folder:

```
700  live
     |--------> 755 company.cxx
                    |------------> 777 fullchain.pem
                    |------------> 777 cert.pem
                    |------------> 777 (etc.)
```

HAProxy is configured like this:

```
frontend public
    bind :80
    bind :443 ssl crt /etc/letsencrypt/live/company.cxx/fullchain.pem
```

And the error is this:

```
Proxy 'public': no SSL certificate specified for bind ':443' at [/etc/haproxy/haproxy.cfg:12] (use 'crt').
Fatal errors found in configuration.
```

I don't know if the permissions are the problem, but **I'm worried about which would be the right way to do this with HAProxy.** I will appreciate your help.

**EDIT:** Just for testing, I tried copying the certificates to `/etc/haproxy` but it didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

The solution is explained on [DigitalOcean](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-secure-haproxy-with-let-s-encrypt-on-ubuntu-14-04). In short:

- Create a pem file concatenating `fullchain.pem` and `privkey.pem`
- Move that new file to `/etc/haproxy/certs`
- Configure HAProxy

Answer (score 1):

As you specified in your own answer, the bare minimum that you need from LetsEncrypt (LE) is a concatenated version of the `fullchain.pem` and `privkey.pem`.

But running the LE client manually every time the cert is going to expire sort of defeats the purpose of using LE.  Additionally, you can't use the LE client in standalone mode if your HAProxy instance is already listening on port 80 for other websites.

As an alternative, you may be interested in this [HAProxy ACME validation plugin](https://github.com/janeczku/haproxy-acme-validation-plugin).

> The plugin leverages HAProxy's Lua API to allow HAProxy to answer validation challenges using token/key-auth files provisioned by an ACME client to a designated directory.

Essentially, you have HAProxy sending all requests that match the well known ACME validation path to a LUA plugin that automatically answers the request for whatever domain is being requested.  You also have a cron job setup that checks the cert expirations on a regular basis and renews them automatically before they expire.  So your only manual step is requesting the initial cert for a domain and adding the PEM reference to your HAProxy config file. After that, the cron job keeps your cert up to date forever (hypothetically).